# Ubuntu 18.04 wi-fi and bluetooth not working simultaneously

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, bluetooth

I have upgraded recently to 18.04 and wi-fi and Bluetooth not working simultaneously (ping drops to about 1500-1600 ms and starts losing packets).

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2130]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 13d3:3408 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Syslog:

```
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation bluetoothd[1846]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_18_09_74_46_AB/fd0: fd(37) ready
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation rtkit-daemon[2158]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation rtkit-daemon[2158]: Successfully made thread 5684 of process 3190 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation rtkit-daemon[2158]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation kernel: [  604.559562] input: 00:18:09:74:46:AB as /devices/virtual/input/input27
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device 00:18:09:74:46:AB (/dev/input/event20)
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) 00:18:09:74:46:AB: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) 00:18:09:74:46:AB: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for '00:18:09:74:46:AB'
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2072]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device 00:18:09:74:46:AB (/dev/input/event20)
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2072]: (**) 00:18:09:74:46:AB: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2072]: (**) 00:18:09:74:46:AB: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2072]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for '00:18:09:74:46:AB'
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event20 13:84 fd 78 paused 0
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) 00:18:09:74:46:AB: always reports core events
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event20"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) event20 - 00:18:09:74:46:AB: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) event20 - 00:18:09:74:46:AB: device is a keyboard
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) event20 - 00:18:09:74:46:AB: device removed
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input27/event20"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "00:18:09:74:46:AB" (type: KEYBOARD, id 19)
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) event20 - 00:18:09:74:46:AB: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) event20 - 00:18:09:74:46:AB: device is a keyboard
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2072]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event20 13:84 fd 26 paused 1
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2072]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:84
Oct  4 22:30:12 nlistation org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3178]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).
Oct  4 22:30:17 nlistation kernel: [  609.124793] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Oct  4 22:30:33 nlistation kernel: [  625.123794] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Oct  4 22:30:49 nlistation kernel: [  641.122788] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Oct  4 22:30:50 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-53 noise=-95 txrate=135000
Oct  4 22:31:01 nlistation CRON[5818]: (nli) CMD (php /var/www/html/rpi-scanner/www/website/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Oct  4 22:31:05 nlistation kernel: [  657.123789] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Oct  4 22:31:06 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2a02:2f0c:8000:3::1.
Oct  4 22:31:06 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=80:8c:97:74:67:e8 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Oct  4 22:31:06 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <warn>  [1538681466.6591] sup-iface[0x55bc40f4f190,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Oct  4 22:31:06 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Oct  4 22:31:06 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681466.6645] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct  4 22:31:06 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681466.7648] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  4 22:31:07 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (SSID='gus' freq=2442 MHz)
Oct  4 22:31:07 nlistation kernel: [  659.706400] wlp3s0: authenticate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8
Oct  4 22:31:07 nlistation kernel: [  659.720556] wlp3s0: send auth to 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 1/3)
Oct  4 22:31:07 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681467.8318] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  4 22:31:08 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (SSID='gus' freq=2442 MHz)
Oct  4 22:31:08 nlistation kernel: [  660.311334] wlp3s0: authenticated
Oct  4 22:31:08 nlistation kernel: [  660.314221] wlp3s0: associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 1/3)
Oct  4 22:31:08 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681468.4269] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct  4 22:31:08 nlistation kernel: [  660.454200] wlp3s0: associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 2/3)
Oct  4 22:31:09 nlistation kernel: [  660.897353] wlp3s0: associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 3/3)
Oct  4 22:31:09 nlistation kernel: [  661.114215] wlp3s0: association with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 timed out
Oct  4 22:31:09 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681469.2599] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Oct  4 22:31:09 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681469.7646] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  4 22:31:16 nlistation kernel: [  668.758795] wlp3s0: authenticate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8
Oct  4 22:31:16 nlistation kernel: [  668.776309] wlp3s0: send auth to 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 1/3)
Oct  4 22:31:16 nlistation kernel: [  668.782244] wlp3s0: authenticated
Oct  4 22:31:16 nlistation kernel: [  668.786273] wlp3s0: associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 1/3)
Oct  4 22:31:16 nlistation kernel: [  668.802277] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Oct  4 22:31:16 nlistation kernel: [  668.802369] wlp3s0: associated
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (SSID='gus' freq=2442 MHz)
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681476.8868] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (SSID='gus' freq=2442 MHz)
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681476.8979] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: Associated with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681476.9179] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681476.9342] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Oct  4 22:31:19 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-61 noise=-95 txrate=60000
Oct  4 22:31:20 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2a02:2f0c:8000:3::1.
Oct  4 22:31:20 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2a02:2f0c:8000:8::1.
Oct  4 22:31:20 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct  4 22:31:21 nlistation kernel: [  673.126793] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Oct  4 22:31:20 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct  4 22:31:22 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2a02:2f0c:8000:3::1.
Oct  4 22:31:25 nlistation org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3178]: [3896:3933:1004/223125.572103:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(396)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Oct  4 22:31:25 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=80:8c:97:74:67:e8 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Oct  4 22:31:25 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <warn>  [1538681485.6468] sup-iface[0x55bc40f4f190,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Oct  4 22:31:25 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Oct  4 22:31:25 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681485.6778] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct  4 22:31:25 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681485.7532] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3178]: [3896:3933:1004/223126.066156:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(396)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (SSID='gus' freq=2442 MHz)
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation kernel: [  678.691155] wlp3s0: authenticate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681486.8190] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation kernel: [  678.708664] wlp3s0: send auth to 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 1/3)
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (SSID='gus' freq=2442 MHz)
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation kernel: [  678.792831] wlp3s0: authenticated
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation kernel: [  678.794410] wlp3s0: associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 1/3)
Oct  4 22:31:26 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681486.9087] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct  4 22:31:27 nlistation kernel: [  679.499001] wlp3s0: associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 2/3)
Oct  4 22:31:28 nlistation kernel: [  680.002373] wlp3s0: associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 3/3)
Oct  4 22:31:28 nlistation kernel: [  680.437118] wlp3s0: association with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 timed out
Oct  4 22:31:28 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681488.5918] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Oct  4 22:31:29 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681489.0960] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (SSID='gus' freq=2442 MHz)
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation kernel: [  688.095709] wlp3s0: authenticate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681496.2230] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation kernel: [  688.112748] wlp3s0: send auth to 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 1/3)
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (SSID='gus' freq=2442 MHz)
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation kernel: [  688.116892] wlp3s0: authenticated
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681496.2324] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation kernel: [  688.122554] wlp3s0: associate with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (try 1/3)
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: Associated with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation kernel: [  688.134616] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation kernel: [  688.134696] wlp3s0: associated
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681496.2500] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 80:8c:97:74:67:e8 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681496.2579] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Oct  4 22:31:36 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-60 noise=-95 txrate=65000
Oct  4 22:31:37 nlistation kernel: [  689.122810] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Oct  4 22:31:39 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2a02:2f0c:8000:3::1.
Oct  4 22:31:40 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2a02:2f0c:8000:8::1.
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation gsd-media-keys[3624]: Unable to get default sink
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 23
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) config/udev: removing device 00:18:09:74:46:AB
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (**) Option "fd" "78"
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) event20 - 00:18:09:74:46:AB: device removed
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3008]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:84
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation gnome-shell[3178]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation bluetoothd[1846]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2a02:2f0c:8000:3::1.
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct  4 22:31:44 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct  4 22:31:45 nlistation NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  [1538681505.2305] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct  4 22:31:45 nlistation dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=1113 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Oct  4 22:31:45 nlistation systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct  4 22:31:45 nlistation dbus-daemon[1015]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct  4 22:31:45 nlistation systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct  4 22:31:45 nlistation nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Oct  4 22:31:45 nlistation nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Oct  4 22:31:46 nlistation wpa_supplicant[1129]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-54 noise=-95 txrate=121500
Oct  4 22:31:47 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2a02:2f0c:8000:8::1.
Oct  4 22:31:49 nlistation systemd-resolved[848]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

According to the official bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1746164

I have created `/etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth-audio.conf` with the following content:

```
options ath9k btcoex_enable=1 bt_ant_diversity=1
```

And it is a temporary fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1746164

I have created `/etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth-audio.conf` with the following content:

```
options ath9k btcoex_enable=1 bt_ant_diversity=1
```